# How to create an array of "mostly equal" integers of a given length and given sum?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a bag of **N** jelly beans, and I want to divide them as evenly as possible among **P** people. I want an array that shows the number of jelly beans each person gets.

For example, I have 23 jelly beans to divide among 5 people. The array should look like `[5, 5, 5, 4, 4]`

I suppose this is more of a math problem, but I'm looking for a solution in javascript.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Please post what you've tried

Comment: `Array(P).fill().map((_, i) => i < N % P ? Math.floor(N / P) + 1 : Math.floor(N / P));`

Comment: @ASDFGerte, nice. Post it as an answer for an upvote.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @ASDFGerte, you could change `Math.floor(N / P) + 1` for `Math.ceil(N / P)`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, I did of course make an attempt in my code, though the use case was more obscure so it wouldn't have made sense to post the exact code. I tried to simplify the question as much as possible. I will try to simplify the attempted answer as well next time.

Comment: If posting what he tried does not clarify the question I dont think it's an issue in this case. His question is legit. He's got 6K rep here. He did not ask "How to make a shopping cart with javascript?" ;)

Comment: @fubar Yes, it's not the best code, i just wrote something that solves the problem really quick. `Array.from` is also preferrable, as it does not create the intermediate array that just produces garbage collector overhead. Writing `.fill().map` is an old habit of mine, i still do it when writing too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fun simple (inefficient) solution, resembling the way small humans often solve this problem.

```js
var P=5
var Nbeans=23
var people=new Array(P).fill(0);

for (var beans=0; beans < Nbeans;beans++){
  people[beans % P]++
}
console.log(people)
```

Or somewhat more efficiently;

```js
P=5
Nbeans=23
people=new Array(P).fill(Math.floor(Nbeans/P));
var beansLeft=Nbeans%P;
for (var luckyOnes=0; luckyOnes < beansLeft;luckyOnes++){
  people[luckyOnes]++
}
console.log(people)
```

Finally if you want to be really efficient and make sure you only address each array element once, you could use the typed array subarray method.

```js
var N=5;
var Nbeans=23;
var people=new Uint32Array(N);
var numLucky=Nbeans%N;
people.subarray(0,numLucky).fill(Math.ceil(Nbeans/N));
people.subarray(numLucky,people.length).fill(Math.floor(Nbeans/N));
console.log(people);
```